# Inverse covariance estimation for generalised Lasso

Tags: optimization, lasso

I have implemented Lasso for estimating sparse inverse covariance case using ADMM in Matlab. Inverse covariance estimation using LASSO regularisation, X is the estimate, S is empirical covariance matrix.

**minimize Tr(SX) - log det X + $\lambda$ ||X||$^1$**

ADMM is 
[image]

But, I actually want to minimize a Generalised version(equation below) of Lasso using ADMM,that is, with W - a weight matrix.  can anyone help me how I can go about solving it using ADMM?

**minimize Tr(SX) - log det X + $\lambda$ ||WX||$^1$**

Comment: For clarity, you *are* asking how to modify this update rule, and not for help developing a software implementation, yes?

Comment: Yes. I need to know how to modify the update rule.

Comment: Thanks. Voting to leave open—how to generalize an update rule seems to me entirely on topic.